# Integrating Unity project into Cordova with mgcrea plugin

Tags: apache, cordova, plugins, unity-game-engine, integration

I have an `Unity 3D` project made for `Android` and I'm trying to port it in `IOS`. I created a similar project with `Apache Cordova` but without `3D graphic`, and now I found a plugin for `Cordova` that promise an Unity integration with `Cordova` (https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-plugin-unity). I've tried to integrate it, but I haven't understand where I must insert my Unity files into `Cordova`.

Unfortunately there isn't a working example and there's a lack of detailed explanation, so I would ask if anyone has already tried that plugin and eventually how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest contacting the author of the plugin directly.

Comment: I wonder if you have aby progress with your issue?

Comment: No progress, I resolved using only Unity, reconstructing the work already done.